# Twilio, is it possible to have 5 minute delays between a call with Rest api?

Tags: php, rest, cron, twilio

I have a sequential dialling app but I want to add 5 minute delays between each call.. I am thinking cron job. is this possible? If so what do I need to do to make this happen? I have no experience with cron..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found sleep function in PHP manual which did just what I needed. Plus its really simple, can't believe not many knew of this.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: I don't know how you can say "not many knew of this," it's just that using the `sleep()` function is not the correct way to implement what you're talking about.

Comment: I could do cron jobs etc but why make it so complicated when I could do it so easily with 1 word of code as compared to a gazillion brain cells dying.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044606/to-use-sleep-or-cron-job or http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?617543-sleep-or-cron-job about why you shouldn't use `sleep()` instead of a cron.

Comment: I have read that cron topic. The crucial difference here is that my script needs to halt its process every 5 minutes, note HALT, cron will call a php script every 5 minutes which isn't what I want. I am sure there are ways to create delays to halt a script using crob but why reinvent that feature when its already there.

Answer (score 6):

I would just set up some sort of queue in a database, then every 5 minutes execute a script that reads the next phone number to call from the queue.  Running a script every 5 minutes with a cron will look like this:

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/call/script.php
```

Comment: Good suggestion. Just remember that PHP's command line environment is often different from the Apache environment and can even use a different php.ini... so if you run into system path or config oddities, check into that first.

Comment: Of course it's much different, but that wasn't the point of the question :).  Because he was specifically asking about PHP, I used PHP as my example script.

Comment: The comment was more for him than you. And mostly to identify a major pitfall before he hit it. I had already given you a +1 :)